# Where to specify custom log file name in GWT application using gwt-log framework?

Tags: java, gwt, logging

I am implementing log in GWT application using [gwt-log](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted) framework. I am not able to find way to specify name of log file with location of my choice.

I have configured this framework to log both client and server side messages.

Has anybody tried this?

Answer (score 0):

GWT-Log, at least on client side, is not designed to log information into a file. It should be used to display data into a console in your UI, as you can test in the [demo](http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.demo.LogDemo/LogDemo.html).
Alternatively, if you want to log user's interaction on client side, you need to implement your own servlet, and send your logs event to the server where they can be logged with log4j for instance.

On server side, you can define the log file name in `log4j.xml` as for any web application using log4j.

Comment: Hi Foch, I have configured servlet as suggested in gwt-log document and I am getting all logs (Client and Server) in console but they are not written to a physical file. So I am wondering why it is not writing logs to a file.

Comment: When I run application through eclipse (Run As Web Application) it prints logs out to an auto generated file with name "logsxxxxx-server.log" but when I create a war of an application it is not pushing log into log file instead it just write to server console.